# Symfony2 Passing instantiated Object to Service, rather than new object

Tags: php, symfony

im looking to pass an already instatiated object to my service constructer, rather than creating a new one, to create a new one i do this:

```
services:
    ExampleService:
        class: Ex\ModelBundle\lib\Ex\ExSave

    LoginService:
        class: Snap\ModelBundle\Service\Login
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@ExampleService"]
```

How would i pass an already instatiated ExampleService to LoginService

Comment: Are you saying that ExampleService should refer to some object that was created outside of the container?  What would be the use case for it?

Answer (score 0):

By default all services have `container` scope which according to docs mean:

> The same instance is used each time you request it from this container.

So, you create your `ExampleService`, but any other, subsequent, request for that service is going to return its previously created instance.

It all boils down to point that multiple services can (and will) use shared instance of your `ExampleService`.

---

Alternately, you could use **[Setter Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection)**.

Basically, you don't pass `@ExampleService` to `__construct` but rather to separate setter which will set the property value (within the service). Then you use your service as usual.